# How print a single field of Db table, using body-parser framework

Tags: node.js, express, body-parser

I have a simple server node that makes a request on a database and prints the results on the browser.
When I make a selection on db I can take all the records of a table but not the individual fields of the table.

I tried to use the "body-parser" framework but with negative results.

```
const express = require('express');
const exphbs  = require('express-handlebars');
const sql = require('mssql');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const config = require('./db/config.json');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

/*TEST CONNECTION*/
app.get('/pippo',function(req,res){

new sql.ConnectionPool(config).connect().then(pool => {
return pool.query(`select _id, titolo, contenuto, data_insert  from note`)
}).then(result => {
res.render('tabella', {
   //rows: result.recordset
   _id: result.body._id,
   titolo: result.body.titolo,
   contenuto: result.body.contenuto,
   data_insert: result.body.data_insert
     });
    }).catch(err => {
console.log('ERROR');
console.log(result.body._id);//PRINT ERROR
    }); 
});
```

This is a print of error:

> ERROR
>   (node:9252) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: result is not defined
>       at sql.ConnectionPool.connect.then.then.catch.err (C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\YYY\Udemy\Progetti\AppMyNote\app.js:36:17)
>       at 
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
>   (node:9252) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
>   (node:9252) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

If i use  this into render, why do not i have problems?:

```
res.render('tabella', {
   rows: result.recordset
     });
    }).catch(err => {
console.log('ERROR');
```

Answer (score 0):

`console.log(result.body._id)` - this statement is inside catch block, and the `result` object is local to your then block, that's why you getting this error.

So to access your `result` object inside the catch block, you need to make it global.

Make following changes to your code:

```
const express = require('express');
const exphbs  = require('express-handlebars');
const sql = require('mssql');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const config = require('./db/config.json');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;
let query_result = null; //add this variable

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

/*TEST CONNECTION*/
app.get('/pippo',function(req,res){

new sql.ConnectionPool(config).connect().then(pool => {
return pool.query(`select _id, titolo, contenuto, data_insert  from note`)
}).then(result => {

query_result = result; 

res.render('tabella', {
   //rows: result.recordset
   _id: result.body._id,
   titolo: result.body.titolo,
   contenuto: result.body.contenuto,
   data_insert: result.body.data_insert
     });
    }).catch(err => {
console.log('ERROR');
console.log(query_result.body._id); 
    }); 
});
```